# Android JobScheduler Implementation

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, scheduler

I am struggling to understand the details of the life of an Android JobScheduler job. The documentation says:

> This is an API for scheduling various types of jobs against the
>   framework that will be executed in your application's own process.

So does this mean that the job will only run when my app is running?

I am performing a cloud data sync that I want to invoke according to a strict schedule, preferably whenever the device is on. I am running on Android 6.0.1. Should I be looking at a different mechanism to schedule this work?

Comment: It is not necessary for your app to be alive for JobScheduler to work. Simply start JobScheduler service using startService().

Comment: I would check out https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/ it is the new support lib way of doing background tasks.

Comment: @TaseerAhmad: This confuses me, since the quote I posted above says "in your application's own process". Also, you'd have to start your app to call startService(). Or is this a one-time call that somehow leaves the job running between reboots?

Comment: @StuartCampbell: Thanks! I'll dig into this!

Comment: @user3352488 You can create your own background thread to do work in your JobScheduler. You can call startService() method while your application is alive OR you can set up a broadcast receiver and start your JobScheduler service on certain intents. If you choose the latter, make sure you register your broadcast in your manifest file.

Comment: @TaseerAhmad: Many thanks, Taseer!

Comment: @TaseerAhmad: This is working nicely apart from the fact my task is not completing. Now to try and find an effective way to debug an ActionBootCompleted intent receiver in Xamarin...

Comment: No.It works in background after scheduled.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/android-job-scheduler

Answer (score 0):

No, Job scheduler schedules job to be run on specific time or specific period, in background. so even if your app is not running, your job will be guaranteed to run.In case of periodic Job there may be some delay, but for exact jobs it's guaranteed to run on time.